# Only logging errors with AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm trying to add few lines of code so that, when my AWS Lambda function fails, it logs when it fails and with which input parameters it did. Following the documentation, I added these lines:

```
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
logger.info('user {0}'.format(event["user"]))
```

They generate some information that are accessible from CloudWatch:

```
08:50:29 - START RequestId: 92d000ad-b01f-11e8-98a6-c32aa1e3e890 Version: $LATEST
08:50:31 - [INFO] 2018-09-04T08:50:31.781Z 92d000ad-b01f-11e8-98a6-c32aa1e3e890 user xxxxxx
08:50:31 - END RequestId: 92d000ad-b01f-11e8-98a6-c32aa1e3e890
08:50:31 - REPORT RequestId: 92d000ad-b01f-11e8-98a6-c32aa1e3e890 Duration: 2513.04 ms Billed Duration: 2600 ms Memory Size: 896 MB Max Memory Used: 37 MB
```

However, it seems that every single call of the lambda function creates a log entry in the CloudWatch. As it is, it's impossible to identify the logs associated to failures of the function. Is it instead possible to create log entries only when `logging` writes the information? In alternative, can an `S3` bucket be set to store log files (associated to errors)?

Comment: What language is this?

Answer (score 0):

Any reason you are not utilizing the log level?

```
logger.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
```

If you need to log all events, and Cloudwatch would be a good place to do that, then you could consider creating a metric filter inside Cloudwatch\Logging, to create alerts for all entries having keyword 'error', as an example.

Comment: Can you please point me to some documentation where I can read about it? I am new to AWS and I have no idea where to start. Thanks

Comment: Documentation about which option, do you want to create a metric filter?

Comment: Sure, it's the first example on this page, [https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/FilterAndPatternSyntax.html] and you will configure it under CloudWatch->Logs, click on the log file and select Create Metric Filter button above.

Comment: Maybe I am wrong, but this simply counts how many times the function failed, I'd like to keep track of all the users for which the function failed. So, I'd need to access the log files where ["ERROR"] is present

Comment: Sorry, this is now more clear. I would still consider using the AWS GUI with cloudwatch logs, with an appropriate filter. A sample error log would help you with writing out the filter. Cloudwatch retains the logs indefinitely by default, so the only concern is filtering them out and exporting the results. GUI actions can be duplicated with the Aws CLI as well. Hope this makes sense.